# Getting a error in Xcode when content gets out of frame

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, contentview

I have always found app development to be very interesting, so I started learning more about Swift in Xcode. Currently, I am working on creating an overview page for cars that are on sale, but I have run into an issue with the content going outside the frame. I attempted to fix the problem by adding a ScrollView on my VStack, but this did not solve the issue.

[image: Error]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color(.white)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            ScrollView{
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20.0)
                {
                    Text("Aanbevolen")
                        .font(.system(size: 36))
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    
                    ForEach(0..<4) { index in
                        Image("car")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                        HStack{
                            Text("145347km")
                                .font(.caption)
                                .padding(.vertical, 5.0)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 10.0)
                                .background(.gray)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                            Text("03/2018")
                                .font(.caption)
                                .padding(.vertical, 5.0)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 10.0)
                                .background(.gray)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                            Text("235kW(320PK)")
                                .font(.caption)
                                .padding(5.0)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 7.0)
                                .background(.gray)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                            
                        }
                        Text("TeslaModel S85 Performance 2015 | MARGE | Free Supercharge")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        Text("€ 24.800,-")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    }
                    Text("Recent toegevoegd")
                        .font(.system(size: 36))
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: Your question title says that you are getting an error in Xcode.  Please include the exact text of that error.

Comment: @ChipJarred I updated the post by including a screenshot of my error

Comment: your code works fine with me on Xcode 14.3 and iOS 16.4 Simulator